# Stop event listener from listing to children elements in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a modal in Vue, which I want to to be able to close whenever the user clicks outside of the inner modal container. The problem is when I add an event listener on click to the parent element all children elements also trigger that event listener when clicked.

I created a simple demo below to demonstrate my problem. If the user clicks on the black portion of the parent element the modal should close but the containing white space of the child element shouldn't be able to trigger the close function.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#modal',
  data: {
    active: true,
  },
  methods: {
    closeModal() {
      this.active = false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.modal.active {
  display: flex;
 }

.modal-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="modal" class="modal" :class="{active: active}" v-on:click="closeModal">
  <div class="modal-content">This child element shouldn't be able to close the modal on click.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool thanks, everyone. I had originally tried the event modifiers but I was using them incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I endorse **kimy82**'s answer. Use [`click.self`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers). Snippet updated.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#modal',
  data: {
    active: true,
  },
  methods: {
    closeModal(event) {
      this.active = false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.modal.active {
  display: flex;
 }

.modal-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="modal" class="modal" :class="{active: active}" v-on:click.self="closeModal">
  <div class="modal-content">This child element shouldn't be able to close the modal on click.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try
v-on:click.self=...
Should only trigger if the target element is itself.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

There are event modifiers for the click event handler
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

```
<!-- modifiers can be chained -->
<a v-on:click.stop.prevent="doThat"></a>
```